# Passing params in Knockout component as a AMD Module

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, amd

My `tagname` component is like below and while the component is registered as a single AMD module, I want to get the all params.

```js
ko.components.register('tagname', { 
  synchronous: true,
  require: params.url
});
```

```html
<tagname params="url: 'some/relative/url'"></tagname>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "want to get the all params"?

Answer (score 0):

The function that you provide for your view model (or as the `createViewModel` factory) will receive all of the params. For example:

```
define(['knockout', 'text!./my-tagname.html'], function(ko, templateString) {
    function MyTagNameComponent(params) {
        // do something with params here
    }

    return { viewModel: MyTagNameComponent, template: templateString };
});
```

So, your component will receive its params as the first argument to `MyTagNameComponent` in this case.

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/g7zhjfz1/

Comment: yup thats what I am doing.. But i want others to provide flexibity to have the url of this viewModel file to be passed as a param to the component.

Comment: With require.js, you could do something like that, but you would have to already require the various view model choices like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/x8809Lhp/. Otherwise, you would have better luck implementing a custom loader. Check out the end of this [post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2014/06/knockout-3-2-preview-components.html) or the loader docs [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html).